# Syntax error when parsing .dta files and attempting to move it to a postgresql server

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to parse .dta files and enter each row into a separate table. The .dta files are composed of a lot of different variables, and I want to insert each variable into a separate "variable table". I am using the new .dta reader from pandas, which is named statareader. I do not have a lot of experience with python, and was hoping for a little help with my syntax. Also I am using python 2.7.5

```
a = 2
t = 1
while t >= 1:
    for date, row in dr.iterrows():
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO (table#'+str(t)') (data) VALUES(%s)" % (row[a]))
    t+=1
    a+=1
    if t == 10:
        break
```

At the cur.execute line, I get the error:

```
pg8000.errors.ProgrammingError: ('ERROR', '42601', 'syntax error at or near "("')
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your code is directly substituting stuff into an SQL query. ***Please don't do that*** - you're opening your application up to all sorts of SQL injection bugs and vulnerabilities. (I suspect that one of them is the root cause of this error.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are generating invalid SQL code. An `INSERT` statement does not accept `()` parenthesis around the table name. To quote a table name (which makes it case sensitive, so be careful) put double quotes around it:

```
cur.execute('INSERT INTO "table#{}" (data) VALUES (%s)'.format(t), (row[a],))
```

The above example also uses proper SQL parameters for the row data; you generally want to let the database prepare a generic statement and reuse the prepared statement for each insert. By using SQL parameters you not only ensure that `row[a]` is properly escaped, but also let the database prepare the generic statement. I used the [default paramstyle format for pg8000](http://pybrary.net/pg8000/dbapi.html#pg8000.dbapi.paramstyle).

You probably want to rethink your `while` loop condition; why not test if `t < 10` instead?

```
a = 2
t = 1
while t < 10:
    for date, row in dr.iterrows():
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO "table#{}" (data) VALUES (%s)'.format(t), (row[a],))
    a += 1
    t += 1
```

or use a python `for` loop with `range()` instead:

```
for t in range(1, 10):
    a = t + 1
    for date, row in dr.iterrows():
        cur.execute('INSERT INTO "table#{}" (data) VALUES (%s)'.format(t), (row[a],))
```